# Adding a fade effect to an image slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a working image slider.

```js
var sliderIndex = 0; // start with the first image
var autoSlideHandler; // for the reset
var activeDuration = 3000; // each picture is active for 3 seconds

startImageSlider();
function startImageSlider() { // Initialize the slider
    sliderIndex++;
    updateImageSlider();
    autoSlideHandler = setTimeout(startImageSlider, activeDuration);
}

function changeSliderImage(direction) { // change images manually by pressing the buttons
    sliderIndex += direction;
    updateImageSlider();
    clearTimeout(autoSlideHandler);
    autoSlideHandler = setTimeout(startImageSlider, activeDuration);
}

function updateImageSlider() { // switch the images
    var sliderImages = $(".sliderImg");

    for (var i = 0; i < sliderImages.length; i++) {
        sliderImages[i].style.display = "none"; // hide the current image
    }
    if (sliderIndex > sliderImages.length) {
        sliderIndex = 1;
    }
    else if (sliderIndex < 1) {
        sliderIndex = sliderImages.length;
    }
    sliderImages[sliderIndex - 1].style.display = "block"; // show the next image
}
```

```css
#containerImageSlider {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(25%);
}

.sliderImg{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.sliderBtn {
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    top: 50%;
    position: absolute;
}

#sliderBtnRight{
    left: -200px;
    /* background-image: url("../../Resources/slideImageLeft.png"); */
}

#sliderBtnLeft{
    right: -200px;
    /* background-image: url("../../Resources/slideImageRight.png"); */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <div id="containerImageSlider">
            <button class="sliderBtn" id="sliderBtnLeft" onclick="changeSliderImage(1)"></button>
            <img class="sliderImg" src="Resources/SliderImages/sliderImg1.jpg">
            <img class="sliderImg" src="Resources/SliderImages/sliderImg2.jpg">
            <img class="sliderImg" src="Resources/SliderImages/sliderImg3.jpg">
            <img class="sliderImg" src="Resources/SliderImages/sliderImg4.jpg">
            <img class="sliderImg" src="Resources/SliderImages/sliderImg5.jpg">
            <img class="sliderImg" src="Resources/SliderImages/sliderImg6.jpg">
            <img class="sliderImg" src="Resources/SliderImages/sliderImg7.jpg">
            <img class="sliderImg" src="Resources/SliderImages/sliderImg8.jpg">
            <img class="sliderImg" src="Resources/SliderImages/sliderImg9.jpg">
            <img class="sliderImg" src="Resources/SliderImages/sliderImg10.jpg">
            <button class="sliderBtn" id="sliderBtnRight" onclick="changeSliderImage(-1)"></button>
        </div>
```

So when calling the function `updateImageSlider()` I want the current Image fading out and the next image fading in.

**Example**

```
$(currentImage).fadeOut(1000, function () {
    // hide the image
});

$(nextImage).fadeIn(1000, function () {
    // show the image
});
```

But when trying to put this code into my existing code it doesn't seem to work fine.

I thought about writing

```
    var currentImage = sliderImages[i];
    $(currentImage).fadeOut(1000, function () {
        currentImage.style.display = "none";
    });
```

and

```
var nextImage = sliderImages[sliderIndex - 1];
$(nextImage).fadeIn(1000, function () {
    nextImage.style.display = "block";
});
```

but this does not fit into my code. The current Image is fading out while the next image is already fading in below the current container...

Comment: do you mean `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` happening in same time?

Comment: as you wish. I just want the current one fading out and the next one fading in.

Comment: if possible create a fiddler, so that can identify what is happening exactly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your `updateImageSlider()` function as like below and check,

```
function updateImageSlider() { // switch the images
  var sliderImages = $(".sliderImg");

  for (var i = 0; i < sliderImages.length; i++) {
    $(sliderImages[i]).fadeOut(1000); // hide the current image
  }
  if (sliderIndex > sliderImages.length) {
    sliderIndex = 1;
  } else if (sliderIndex < 1) {
    sliderIndex = sliderImages.length;
  }

  setTimeout(function() {
    $(sliderImages[sliderIndex - 1]).fadeIn(1000); // show the next image
  }, 1000);
}
```

Check this [fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/rajsnd08/wyLwz51z/1/) for reference.

Comment: almost! when setting the timeout to 3 seconds, it still switches each second

Comment: what ever time you set it for `fadeOut` use it on `setTimeout` means it will be waiting to start showing next image.

Comment: Ah, now I understood!

Comment: So when writing `$(sliderImages[i]).fadeOut();` and `setTimeout(function() {
        $(sliderImages[sliderIndex - 1]).fadeIn();
    }, 500);` what do I need to paste in, making the fading slower and the duration of the shown image longer?

Comment: I want it to fade out / in 1000 milliseconds, the shown image should last for 3000 milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

Tried to apply the below updateImageSlider() Function :

```
function updateImageSlider() { // switch the images
    var sliderImages = $(".sliderImg");

    for (var i = 0; i < sliderImages.length; i++) {
         sliderImages[i].css('display','none').fadeOut(); // hide the current image
    }
    if (sliderIndex > sliderImages.length) {
        sliderIndex = 1;
    }
    else if (sliderIndex < 1) {
        sliderIndex = sliderImages.length;
    }
    sliderImages[sliderIndex - 1].css('display','block').fadeIn(); // show the next image
}
```

Comment: there is no error when writing `$(sliderImages[sliderIndex - 1]).css('display','block').fadeIn(1000);` but the images slide instant. There is no fade animation